# What is the rationale of solving SDE by Ito's formula?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

When solving a SDE by Ito's formula, we have to find a function $f(t, X_t)$ of index $t$ and the process $X$ to be solved for.

1. I was wondering  what is the criterion of choosing $f$? Is it to
   make the integrands not contain $X$?
2. How is $f$  chosen in principle?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular SDE. There is no systematic approach.

One main idea is striving for some cancelation to simplify the drift/volatility coefficients (eg.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823785/stochastic-differential-equation-with-trigonometric-functions). For example, in [Geometric Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#:%7E:text=A%20geometric%20Brownian%20motion%20(GBM,a%20Wiener%20process)%20with%20drift.)

$$ dS_t = \mu S_t\,dt + \sigma S_t\,dW_t$$

one observes the $S_{t}$ term would cancel out with the derivative of $f(x)=log(x)$.

Another idea is to help transfer some ODE techniques such as integration-factor see here.
[Solution to General Linear SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788853/solution-to-general-linear-sde)