# Stochastic Differential equations with $\sin(x^2)$ as drift.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Can somebody help me how to solve the following SDE analytically or suggest me to go through some literature to understand this or can give me a little bit hint to work by myself.
Thanks in advance.

$dX(t) =\sin (X(t)^2) dt + \cos (X(t)-2) dB(t),\quad  X(0) = 1.$

Comment: Dear gebruiker, quite thankful to you for editing. Im quite new here in stack exchange so dont know how to use this much.

Comment: Do you want to solve the SDE numerically? Or is there any reason which makes you believe that there exists an analytic solution? There are some standard approaches how to solve SDEs analytically, but as far as I can see they do not apply to this particular SDE.

Comment: Dear Saz, Yes I want to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments an analytic solution seems out of reach.

- one cannot simplify by removing the drift as done in Shreve-Karatzas because the volatility coefficient has zeroes.
- There is no clear trigonometric identity to use here for $\sin(x^{2})$ as one could in a related one to simplify [Stochastic differential equation with trigonometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823785/stochastic-differential-equation-with-trigonometric-functions).

In terms of numerics, there are many methods out there eg. see ["Lecture 9: Numerically solving SDEs"](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture9_2019.pdf).

Comment: Remark on "Lecture 9": The wikipedia entry on the RK method uses the Heun scheme as basis, is structurally more symmetric and might have half an order more in the weak convergence. The implicit methods that are presented need a correction in the drift coefficient, because $(Dw_t)^2=dt$ gives a non-vanishing contribution in the series inversion. This is not a problem in the second, improved or split method.